# Is it possible to make return statement dependent on the type of instance in python?

Tags: python, return

It is hard to formulate a question… I want to create a function that can return for example string OR list. It will return depends on the type of instance this value is assigned to latter. For example, consider the following code attempt:

```
def do_something():
    some_list = [1, 4, 7, 8]
    some_text = "Hello"
    return some_text or some_list


text: str = do_something()  # want text to become some_text (i.e. "Hello")
List: list[int] = do_something()  # List should take some_list value (so [1, 4, 7, 8])
print(text, List)  # want it to print < Hello [1, 4, 7, 8] >
```

I know, that the following code will not work for obvious reasons. I also know that I can return a list or a tuple in return statement, like  `return some_text, some_list`. But then I will need to state, which value to take and I really don't want to make something like `text: str = do_something()[0]`.

That is because I just want to create a function that will return main value (function main task) and some additional that is less important and fully optional. Using tuple for me means that they are both equally important, but they are not, by default return always should return the first value. Can I do that in python, or is it completely impossible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Functions have no access to what the caller will do with the result. Also, type annotations are totally ignored by the interpreter.

Comment: "It will return depends on the type of instance this value is assigned to latter." that is not possible (in any sane way at least), and certainly not desirable. The assignment happens **after** the return is completed.

Comment: What should `print(do_something())` do?

Comment: Also note, you don't **assign to an instance**. You *return* an instance, which gets *assigned* to a variable (or not).

Comment: In general, it is best to avoid a function that can return multiple different types of objects to begin with. Much better off just having another function

Comment: @Barmar return the first value, i.e. some_text. But I see your point

Comment: You could have a result based on a dataclass with the main/always value and the secondary optional value defaulted to None.

Comment: @JLPeyret this is essentially the same idea as the tuple suggestion, which for some reason, isn't desirable

Comment: This question might benefit from a clearer example:  this is what it looks like in case 1, this is what it looks like in case 2.  function body but also caller interaction with the result.   Also, are these really functions?  Or methods - you talk about “attached to values” and “instances”.

Comment: I know that assignment happens after the return. That just was a theoretical question, in my dreams that should return an optional data (dreams…) and then python could decide, which value to use depends on the type hint. Also I know that it is better to avoid return different types (similar to use one variable for different types). But thanks anyone for the quick reply and for disillusionment!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Your best call would probably be to either create a second function to return the other data type or to pass what you want to the function:

```
def do_something(as_list = False):
    some_list = [1, 4, 7, 8]
    some_text = "Hello"
    if as_list:
        return some_list
    else:
        return some_text    

text: str = do_something()  # want text to become some_text (i.e. "Hello")
List: list[int] = do_something(as_list=True)  # List should take some_list value (so [1, 4, 7, 8])
print(text, List)  # want it to print < Hello [1, 4, 7, 8] >
```

Whether you create a different function or pass it as an argument mostly depends on your business logic and needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for something like this:

```py
def do_something(var):
    some_list = [1, 4, 7, 8]
    some_text = "Hello"
    if type(var) == str:
        return some_text
    elif type(var) == list:
        return some_list
    else:
        return None

text = ""
text = do_something(text)

lst = []
lst = do_something(lst)

print(text, lst)
```

Which results in

```
Hello [1, 4, 7, 8]
```